# cómo modificar el header de una respuesta en función de la llamada? (.net core 3.1)

Tags: api, asp.net-core, headers

os explico mi problema:

Tengo que crear un único proyecto net core 3.1 para crear una api. Sencillo, no?

Bueno, pues esta es la complicación: según se haga una llamada u otra, el conjunto de cabeceras de la respuesta http, (httpresponse) es uno u otro.

Entonces, he googleado un poco y he encontrado lo siguiente: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/http-response-headers-asp-net-core/:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Add a sample response header 
    app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleware) =>
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Site", "Simple-Talk");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
        await nextMiddleware();
    });
 
    app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleware) =>
    {
        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var originalStream = context.Response.Body;
            context.Response.Body = memory;
 
            await nextMiddleware();
 
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var content = new StreamReader(memory).ReadToEnd();
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 
            // Apply logic here for deciding which headers to add
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Body", content);
 
            await memory.CopyToAsync(originalStream);
            context.Response.Body = originalStream;
        }
    });
 
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        var obj = new SomeWork();
        await context
            .Response
            .WriteAsync("<h1 style='color:red;'>" + obj.Now() + "</h1>");
    });
}
```

Mi pregunta es cómo consigo la llamada api, para saber qué cabecera (header) añadir porque esto se ejecuta al iniciar el servidor. Entiendo que la cabecera se ha añadido al principio y no al producir la respuesta.

Bueno, pues este es mi código:

```
app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleware) =>
            {
                context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
                {
                    //if there is not a valid token and it is not a login request
                    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("x-session-token"))
                    {
                        var token = context.Request.Headers["x-session-token"].ToString();
                        var time = DateTime.Now;
                        var expireDate = tokenDetails[token];
                        if (expireDate < time)
                        {
                            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                    else if (context.Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("login"))
                    {
                        // if it is from a login request
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-headers", "authorization, content-type, x-session-token");
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-origin", "*");
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("x-session-token", getToken());
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-max-age", "0");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                    //else
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401; // falla aqui
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                });
                await nextMiddleware();
            });
```

el servidor se queda petado y no termina de arrancar, alguien entiende qué está pasando y cómo arreglarlo?

Comment: Hola has intentado escribir en el response directamente el contenido de los headers? por ejemplo : Response.SetStatus = 404,, Response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "...");

Comment: lo que necesito es añadir un token en algun caso, no en todos. El problema es que tengo que simular una api externa que ya existe, entonces no tengo mucha opcion, las respuestas tienen que ser como las de la api externa

Comment: Hola Iria 2 preguntas: **1** ¿La falla que mencionas genera alguna exception? **2** ¿en que posición de la lista de middleware colocaste el código?. Dime cual es el middleware que le sigue

Comment: hola! solo hay ese middleware, uso swagger pero su configuracion y set up va despues, no entiendo muy bien el middleware, la verdad. No genera excepcion, da pagina de error en vez de mostrarme swagger

Answer (score 2):

No encuentro problemas en el código que publicaste, lo inserté en mi configuración y aunque no es igual a la tuya, funciona sin errores. Es importante tener en cuenta que el [orden en que se colocan los middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order) debe ser tomado en cuenta. En las pruebas que hice, encontré una que produjo un 'comportamiento' similar al que reportas pero se resolvió al cambiarlo de posición.

*Prueba colocar tu código después de la configuración del swagger.*

En los middleware, cada bloque `app.Use...` puede verse como un eslabón de una cadena que ejecuta una acción sobre el Request o el Response y decide si le pasa la ejecución al siguiente (con `await nextMiddleware();`) o interrumpe la secuencia.

Cuando recibe un Request, el orden de ejecución es el mismo como se escribe la lista de `app.Use...` en el método `Configure` (de arriba hacia abajo), pero cuando envía la respuesta la secuencia de ejecución va en orden inverso. (de abajo hacia arriba)

Comment: poniéndolo detrás del swagger funciona pero no entiendo por qué, en qué afecta que sea antes o después, no entiendo lo del orden de ejecucion porque no entiendo bien el concepto de middleware

Comment: puesto detrás del swagger no me añade la cabecera que quiero

Comment: @Iria, es posible para ti editar la pregunta y colocar el método `Configure` completo, con esa información tal vez pueda hacer pruebas con un escenario más parecido al tuyo.